# WebGL Instancing without flags

Tags: webgl, opengl-es-2.0, instance

I'm trying to draw the same mesh a lot of times so I want to instance it but I wanted to know if there's a solution that doesn't require you to enable any of the chrome flags so normal users who wouldn't have those flags enabled could also view the project.

The two options I know of are ANGLE_Instanced_arrays (which requires the draft flag on) and WebGL2.0 has built in instancing but it requires the WebGL2.0 flag on. So are there any other alternatives to this that isn't in development right now?

Comment: afaik `ANGLE_instanced_arrays` does not require a flag to be toggled.

Comment: What LJ said, `ANGLE_instance_arrays` does not require a flag and is [available almost everyhere](http://webglstats.com/)